# Retrieve the version of a dependency in build.rs script

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I would like to expose in my REPL (built on top of Boa) the version of the js engine:

I'm trying to use a `build.rs` file for that:

```
use std::env;
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-env=BOA_VERSION={}", "0.16.0");
}
```

And somewhere in my `main.rs`:

```
context.register_global_property("BOA_VERSION", env!("BOA_VERSION"), Attribute::all());
```

Obviously I have hardcoded the version of the crate but wondering if there is a programmatically way to get the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to get access to the version information in your code, you can skip making a `build.rs` file for it. Instead, we can use the `serde` and `toml` crates to parse your `Cargo.toml` file directly. Below is a sample of how that might look.

Cargo.toml:

```ini
[package]
name = "dependency-information"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0.152", features = ["derive"] }
toml = "0.7.0"
```

main.rs:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum DependencyValue {
    String(String),
    Object {
        version: String,
        features: Vec<String>,
    },
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct CargoToml {
    dependencies: HashMap<String, DependencyValue>,
}

fn main() {
    let cargo_toml_raw = include_str!("../Cargo.toml");
    let cargo_toml: CargoToml = toml::from_str(cargo_toml_raw).unwrap();

    println!("{cargo_toml:#?}");
}
```

And if we run it, we get this output:

```
CargoToml {
    dependencies: {
        "toml": String(
            "0.7.0",
        ),
        "serde": Object {
            version: "1.0.152",
            features: [
                "derive",
            ],
        },
    },
}
```

Note that you probably would want to include the `Cargo.toml` file dynamically instead of using `include_str!`. I used `include_str!` for the sake of the example.

Comment: I think the point was not to be something dynamic, and so all code in your answer should go to build.rs build up the environment variable to be able at compile time.

Comment: @Stargateur, spot on, that was more my question. Sorry for being a bit unclear.